# ANT waiting for file creation

Tags: java, ant, build, wait

is it possible to configure the ANT to pause the building process untill a file is created (with relative timeout)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
<waitfor maxwait="30" maxwaitunit="second">
    <available file="myfile"/>
</waitfor>
```

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the [waitfor](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/waitfor.html) task.